Deleting S3 objects of a specific storage class/tier from a bucket?
Context: I have a bucket with eighty million objects.
A small number of those objects (within the past month) are in the Glacier Flexible Retrieval tier and I no longer need those objects. All other objects in the bucket are in Standard tier storage.
Problem: How can I batch/bulk delete only those objects that are in the Glacier tier?

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an easy method. S3 Batch Operations does not support Delete. S3 Lifecycle does not have the ability to filter based on Storage Class. You could use S3 Inventory to obtain a bucket listing and then extract the Keys for the object you wish to delete and then delete them via an SDK or the AWS CLI. Or, you could write a program that lists the bucket, finds the objects and deletes them. It would only be able to retrieve 1000 objects at a time, so it would need to loop 80,000 times and would be slow.

This is also interesting: Most efficient way to batch delete S3 Files - Server Fault
